# In Python, why do files iterate line by lines but their read() method goes char by char?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I would like to understand why Python's built-in iterator for file-handling goes line by line (I suppose by identifying "/n"?) whereas the built in `read()` method goes through the file character by character. Why is this?